# What's the Comparer<T> class for?

Tags: c#

What purpose does the `Comparer<T>` class serve if the type that you specify already implements `IComparable`?

If I specify Comparer.Default, and Customer already implements IComparable, then why would I use the Comparer class?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Are you asking why having an interface so similar to an abstract class? If so, "the type that you specify" is confusing...

Comment: Psycho - on the scenario you describe, you don't need `Comparer<Customer>`. However, `Customer` may not implement `IComparable` - it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think your question is why have a base class that only seems to have one useful method which happens to be the same method you'd implement if you implemented the interface directly. If I understood that correctly I guess you're right that there's not much benefit to deriving from `Comparer<T>` as opposed to implementing `IComparer<T>` directly except that the base class provides you with a generic and non-generic implementation with a single overridden method.

But if your question is why have both `IComparer<T>` and `IComparable<T>`, then
as others have indicated, `Comparer<T>` allows you to define different ways to perform the comparison. It is an implementation of the [Strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). A great example of this would be the various `StringComparer` properties such as StringComparer.Ordinal, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase, etc. This allows you to sort strings differently under different circumstances which the `IComparable<T>` interface simply cannot anticipate.

But in addition to being able to re-define the way a comparison is performed, sometimes providing an external comparer is the only way you can do it. For example, the Windows Forms ListView class allows you to specify an IComparer for its sort logic. But ListViewItem does not implement IComparable. So without a comparer strategy that knows how to do it, ListViewItem is not sortable because it has no default IComparable implementation.

So at the end of the day, it's just another extensibility point that allows you more flexibility when you're not the author of the type that is to be sorted (or you need multiple sorting strategies.)

---

EDIT: In response to your comment below: *"if I have a class that implements IComparer (my own class), this would allow me to sort on any number of properties (a custom sort), why then would I bother using Comparer.Default"*

Perhaps an example would help. Let's say you're writing an extension method that checks to see if a given value is between a range.

```
public static bool Between<T>(this T value, T minValue, T maxValue) {

    var comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;

    int c1 = comparer.Compare(value, minValue);
    int c2 = comparer.Compare(value, maxValue);

    return (c1 >= 0 && c2 <= 0);

}
```

In this case, I don't know anything about the type T. It may implement `IComparable` or it may implement `IComparable<T>` or it may implement neither and an exception will be thrown. This also allows me to easily add an overload for this method that lets the caller pass in their own comparer. But Comparer comes in handy here because it lets me get a default comparer for an unknown type that may or may not implement a generic or non-generic IComparable interface.

Comment: I added an example to my answer, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Josh, the example helped out in my understanding. One question though, you said "The default comparer for an unknown type that may or may not implement a generic or non-generic IComparable interface." I know that the Comparer throws an exception if a class doesn't implment IComparable so wouldn't I always want to put a constraint on T to implement this interface?

Comment: Well ordinarily, yes you would but because IComparable(of T) doesn't derive from IComparable, you can't really specify a generic constraint that requires the generic OR nongeneric implementation.

Comment: _"or it may implement neither and an exception will be thrown"_ - you can have the compiler check that the type implements `IComparable<T>` using `where` so that should never happen

Answer (score 23):

Because you need sometimes keep sets/ordered queues ordered by something else then 'natural' order or more then one natural order exists.

For example if you have plane lines you may want to sort it by:

- Flight number
- Destination
- Time
- Priority (some flights can suffer longer delays then others)
- ...

Tasks in computer can be scheduled by:

- User
- Priority (in scheduler)
- PID (normal comparation)
- ...

So even in one application you may need to sort the objects by different properties. You cannot do this by `int compareTo(Object)` method as it cannot differentatie between contexts. However you can add the context i.e. implement `CompareByPriority`.

Answer (score 9):

The type doesn't need to implement IComparable, it can be any type - **there are no constrains on `T`**:

```
public abstract class Comparer<T> : IComparer, IComparer<T>
```

The new `Comparer` you create implements `IComparer<T>` and the non-generic `IComparer`, and can be used for comparisons and sorting of collections.

You are correct: if your type, `Customer` implements `IComparable`, and you don't need another comparison, `Comparer` isn't useful to you. Most classes in the .net framework can accept both `IComparable<T>` or `Comparer<T>`, so you can use either one.

However, you are wrong to assume that is always the case. It is very possible to create a `Comparer` for a non-Comparable type. Note that the following is **not** required:

```
public abstract class Comparer<T> : IComparer, IComparer<T>
                                    where T : IComparable, IComparable<T>
```

Suppose you have a simple class, `Person` and you want to sort a list of `Persons`, your best bet it to write a Comparer:

```
public class Person
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There are a few subtle points here:

- it doesn't just support `IComparable<T>` - it also supports the older (non-generic) `IComparable` as a fallback. This means that it *can't* be expressed just as (for example) a generic constraint
- it supports `Nullable<T>` where `T` is comparable, even though `Nullable<T>` clearly **isn't** `IComparable` or `IComparable<T>`
- it prevents explosion of generic type constraints by *not* demanding them - for examle, a `List<T>` can provide a `Sort` even though it doesn't *insist* that all `T` are sortable; you'd be *amazed* how quickly the generic constraints would otherwise accumulate
- it allows you to pass a *comparer* into any of the existing APIs that demand a comparer, when all you have is a *type* that may be comparable; most of the framework sorting APIs (including LINQ) will offer comparer support

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Person
{
    public string LastName;
    public string FirstName;

}

public class Class2
{
    public void test()
    {
        List<Person> classList = new List<Person>();
        //add some data to the list
        PersonComparer comp = new PersonComparer();
        classList.Sort(comp);
    }
}

public class PersonComparer : Comparer<Person>
{

    public override int Compare(Person x, Person y)
    {
        int val = x.LastName.CompareTo(y.LastName);
        if (val == 0)
        {
            val = x.FirstName.CompareTo(y.FirstName);
        }
        return val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but in this case, why not just use IComparer<Person> ??

Comment: because in this case you want to do a special comparison.  You want to compare them by last name first, then by first name.  You could also put an enumeration in your construtor that took a compare option.  Something like public enum PersonSortOption{ BirthDate, LastName, FirstName, Height, Wheight, HairColor }  then in your compare method use a switch to compare/ sort them correctly

Answer (score 1):

If a type implements `IComparable<T>`, it is almost certainly better to use that than `IComparable`.  With value types, the performance of `IComparable<T>` is often much better than that of the non-generic `IComparable`.  With inheritable reference types, `IComparable<T>` can offer better semantics than `IComparable` by allowing rankings based upon derived-type fields.

For an example of the latter benefit, suppose one has an abstract base class `ScheduleEvent`, with a property `EventTime`, that implements `IComparable<ScheduleEvent>` by sorting `EventTime`.  Derived types include `ScheduledPopupMessageEvent` with a message string, a `ScheduledGongEvent` with a `GongVolume` parameter.  Multiple `ScheduleEvent`s with the same `EventTime` must report zero for `IComparable<ScheduleEvent>.CompareTo`, because there is no safe and consistent way to rank `ScheduleEvent`s of different types, and because two `ScheduleEvent`s which both report themselves as unranked relative to a third must, for consistency, report themselves as unranked relative to each other.  On the other hand, there would be no problem with having `ScheduledGongEvent` implementing `IComparable<ScheduledGongEvent>` take `GongVolume` into account as well as `EventTime`, or with `ScheduledPopupMessageEvent` doing likewise with its Message parameter.

It is useful, then, to have things like sorting routines use `IComparable<T>` if it exists, but be able to fall back to `IComparable` if `IComparable<T>` does not exist.  Checking for whether a class implements `IComparable<T>` and selecting an appropriate implementation if it does, however, is a little expensive.  Fortunately, once a type is determined to have an `IComparable<T>` implementation, it can be relied upon to always have one; likewise, if a type is found not to have such an implementation, it never will.  Further, if a generic class has any static fields, every combination of type parameters will yield a different class with different fields.  Thus, the first time `Comparer<T>.Default` is run with a particular type parameter T, it will store the Comparer routine it returns into a static field.  If `Comparer<T>` is run again with that same type, it will return the same comparer routine.  Although it might seem odd to have a static `Comparer<T>` class with just one method, creating a separate `Comparer<T>` class for every type `T` provides a place to store the created compare routine.

Answer (score 0):

`Comparer<T>` holds an actual compare method. It can be used if you want to compare the object differently than in your `IComparable` implementation.