# Using IComparer<T>.Compare(T,T) in C#

Tags: c#, icomparer

I've been trying to make a generic  Reverse Priority Queue, but int the EnQueue, but I still can't manage the errors that come with using IComparer.

The Error: Error    1   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer.Compare(T, T)'

```
public void inQ(T dat)//adding element in place, increasing order
    {
        if (start == null)//that means that the RPQ is empty
        {
            start = new node(dat);
            return;
        }
        if (IComparer<T>.Compare(start.data, dat) > 0)//Doesn't work
        {
            start = new node(dat, start);
            return;
        }
        //Default Case
        //no need for an else, actually
        node q = start;
        while (q.next != null && Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(q.next.data, dat) < 0)//Works Perfectly
            q++;
        q.next = new node(dat, q.next);
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## What happened

you need an instance of `IComparer<T>` to be able to call the method `Compare` on it... remember this is an interface, it doesn't have static methods.

That's why this doesn't work:

```
IComparer<T>.Compare(start.data, dat) > 0
```

On the other hand `Comparer<T>` is a class and it offers you an static property `Default` that gives you an instance of `IComparer<T>`...

That's why this works:

```
Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(q.next.data, dat) < 0
```

---

## Getting an instance of `IComparer<T>`

You can consider storing a field with your instance of `IComparer<T>` and using that instead. That will minimize confusion, and also allow you to get an `IComparer<T>` in the constructor to be stored on that field - which is useful in case the client wants a custom behaviour.

---

### The default instance

If you want to use the default comparer you can get it from  it:

```
var comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
```

This comparer will give the default behaviour for whatever `T` you use. This behaviour is equivalent to calling `CompareTo` on the instances of `T`, with extra handling for nulls. Since you cannot use the method `CompareTo` when your intance is null you may want to check for null before calling `CompareTo`... using a comparer removes the problem.

---

### Implementing `IComparer<T>`

Since `IComparer<T>` is an interface, you can write a class to implement it, that class must have a `Compare` method with whatever logic you want. Then you create an instance of that class and use it where the system wants an `IComparer<T>`.

[See the an example of implementing `IComparer<T>` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

```
// This class is not demonstrated in the Main method 
// and is provided only to show how to implement 
// the interface. It is recommended to derive 
// from Comparer<T> instead of implementing IComparer<T>. 
public class BoxComp : IComparer<Box>
{
    // Compares by Height, Length, and Width. 
    public int Compare(Box x, Box y)
    {
        if (x.Height.CompareTo(y.Height) != 0)
        {
            return x.Height.CompareTo(y.Height);
        }
        else if (x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length) != 0)
        {
            return x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);
        }
        else if (x.Width.CompareTo(y.Width) != 0)
        {
            return x.Width.CompareTo(y.Width);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Your comparer would be an instance of the class:

```
var comparer = new BoxComp();
```

**Note**: the documentation actually suggest to inherit from `Comparer<T>` instead of implementing `IComparer<T>` directly, the pragmatic reason is that `Comparer<T>` also implements `IComparer` in addition of `IComparer<T>`.

---

### Creating an `IComparer<T>` with a delegate

In case you are not familiar with what a delegate is, let's say it is a reference to a method, so you can have a variable that has a reference to method and pass it around.

You can create an `IComparer<T>` if you have a delegate to a method that does the comparison... this is done by calling the method [`Comparer<T>.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737198.aspx) witch will take a delegate to the method you want. For example you can use a lambda expresion as follows:

```
var comparer = Comparer<string>.Create
(
    (str1, str2) => str1.Length.CompareTo(str2.Length)
);
```

The code above is a shorthand for this:

```
Comparison<string> comparison = (str1, str2) => str1.Length.CompareTo(str2.Length);
var comparer = Comparer<string>.Create(comparison);
```

Which in turn is a shorthand for this:

```
Comparison<string> comparison = delegate(string str1, string str2)
{
   return str1.Length.CompareTo(str2.Length);
};
var comparer = Comparer<string>.Create(comparison);
```

Which is sugar for something like this (except that in the above code the method is anonymous):

```
Comparison<string> comparison = StringComparison;
var comparer = Comparer<string>.Create(comparison);

// ...

private static int StringComparison(string str1, string str2)
{
    return str1.Length.CompareTo(str2.Length);
}
```

---

**Extra readings**:

- [What's the Comparer class for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843212/whats-the-comparert-class-for)
- [C#/.NET Little Wonders: Comparer.Default](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/01/20/c.net-little-wonders-comparerlttgt.default.aspx)
- [How to use the IComparable and IComparer interfaces in Visual C#](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/320727)
- [How to Implement IComparable Interface in Base and Derived Classes](http://www.sysexpand.com/?path=howto/implement-icomparable-t)

Comment: Does Comparer<T> work with any custom Compare<T> method I make?

Comment: Since `IComparer<T>` is an interface, you can write a class to implement it, that class must have a `Compare` method with whatever logic you want. Then you create an instance of that class and use it where the system wants an `IComparer<T>`. [See the an example of implementing `IComparer<T>` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Comment: @Sherbi7y `Comparer<T>.Default` will not use a custom `IComparer<T>` that you create. `Comparer<T>` does not discover custom implementations. If you want to use a custom comparer, you need to get an instance of it and use it [See on the answer how to get one]. it is common practice - if your class needs it - to have an overload of the constructor that takes an `IComparer<T>`, and if none is provided fallback to `Comparer<T>.Default` instead. Something like this `_comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;`.